# Getting an error: AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks' at flatten layer for flattening the embedding output

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

## Running LSTM and embedding layer in keras

**Issue is happening when we are running the flatten keras code.**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,concatenate,Activation,Dropout,Input,LSTM,Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

input_layer1 = Input(shape=(48432,), dtype='int32', name='input_layer1')
embed_text = Embedding(48432, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=1300, trainable=False) 
(input_layer1)
#embed = tf.reshape(embed_text(5,48432,100))
text_LSTM = LSTM(32,input_shape=(48432,100),return_sequences=True)(embed_text)
flatten_layer1 = Flatten()(text_LSTM)

#school state Input layer
input_layer2 = Input(shape=(50000,), dtype='int32', name='input_layer2')
embed_school_state = Embedding(30000, 100, input_length=1, trainable=True)(input_layer2)
flatten_layer1 = Flatten()(embed_school_state)
```

*below is the error message*

*AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
* in 
*     20 input_layer2 = Input(shape=(50000,), dtype='int32', name='input_layer2')
*     21 embed_school_state = Embedding(30000, 100, input_length=1, *trainable=True)(input_layer2)
*---> 22 flatten_layer1 = Flatten()(embed_school_state)

*\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in **call**(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
*    474             # Handle mask propagation.
*--> 475             previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
*    476             user_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
*    477             if not is_all_none(previous_mask):

*~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in *_collect_previous_mask(input_tensors)
*   1439             inbound_layer, node_index, tensor_index = x._keras_history
*   1440             node = inbound_layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
*-> 1441             mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
*   1442             masks.append(mask)
**AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'        **

Comment: Please, provide more details about the issue

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: @ AMC below is the reproducible code which will result in error :                                                  
input_layer2 = Input(shape=(50000,), dtype='int32', name='input_layer2')
embed_school_state = Embedding(30000, 100, input_length=1, trainable=True)(input_layer2)
flatten_layer1 = Flatten()(embed_school_state)

Comment: The issue has been resolved after i used only  below keras.layers package without calling tensorflow.keras                                                                                                     from keras.layers import Dense,concatenate,Activation,Dropout,Input,LSTM,Embedding
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential